# mathematical movable mesh in swift with SceneKit

Tags: swift, animation, scenekit, metal

I am a mathematician who wants to program a geometric game.

I have the exact coordinates, and math formulae, of a few meshes I need to display and of their unit normals.

I need only one texture (colored reflective metal) per mesh.

I need to have the user move pieces, i.e. change the coordinates of a mesh, again by a simple math formula.

So I don't need to import 3D files, but rather I can compute everything.

Imagine a kind of Rubik cube. Cube coordinates are computed, and cubelets are rotated by the user. I have the program functioning in Mathematica.

I am having a very hard time, for sleepless days now, trying to find exactly how to display a computed mesh in SceneKit - with each vertex and normal animated separately.

ANY working example of, say, a single triangle with computed coordinates (rather than a stock provided shape), displayed with animatable coordinates by SceneKit would be EXTREMELY appreciated.

I looked more, and it seems that individual points of a mesh may not be movable in SceneKit. I like from SceneKit (unlike OpenGL) the feature that one can get the objects under the user's finger. Can one mix together OpenGL and SceneKit in a project?

I could take over from there....

Comment: Have a look [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47818/how-do-i-create-geometry-in-scenekit) (There's the "geometryWithSources:" method which is I believe exactly what you were looking for)

Comment: Thank you, Kametrixom. Is it true that the position and normal of individual vertices of a mesh cannot be animated in SceneKit? If so can one mix SceneKit with OpenGL for the purpose of animating the individual vertices?

Comment: I don't know about that, but if you really need some more control over what exactly happens, I suggest using Metal. I'm learning it right now and it's really not that difficult (OpenGL is a lot harder and weirder I think). I couldn't find whether it's possible to mix Metal and SceneKit but I guess you could give it a try

Comment: Kametrixom I found in the SceneKit reference that it can call Metal. It is not clear to me whether one needs to initialize Metal, or whether SceneKit does it for you.

Comment: Kametrixom See also [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941797/using-a-metal-shader-in-scenekit?rq=1) It is not clear to me whether one needs to initialize Metal, or whether SceneKit does it for you. Where are you learning Metal from? Just the Apple reference?

Answer (score 10):

Animating vertex positions individually is, in general, a tricky problem. But there are good ways to approach it in SceneKit.

A GPU really wants to have vertex data all uploaded in one chunk before it starts rendering a frame. That means that if you're continually calculating new vertex positions/normals/etc on the CPU, you have the problem of schlepping *all* that data over to the GPU every time even just part of it changes.

Because you're already describing your surface mathematically, you're in a good position to do that work on the GPU itself. If each vertex position is a function of some variable, you can write that function in a shader, and find a way to pass the input variable per vertex.

There are a couple of options you could look at for this:

1. Shader modifiers. Start with a dummy geometry that has the topology you need (number of vertices & how they're connected as polygons). Pass your input variable as an extra texture, and in your shader modifier code (for the geometry entry point), lookup the texture, do your function, and set the vertex position with the result.
2. Metal compute shaders. Create a geometry source [backed by a Metal buffer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNGeometrySource_Class/index.html#/apple_ref/occ/clm/SCNGeometrySource/geometrySourceWithBuffer:vertexFormat:semantic:vertexCount:dataOffset:dataStride:), then at render time, enqueue a compute shader that writes vertex data to that buffer according to your function. (There's skeletal code for part of that at the link.)

---

*Update:* From your comments it sounds like you might be in an easier position.

If what you have is geometry composed of pieces that are static with respect to themselves and move with respect to each other — like the cubelets of a Rubik's cube — computing vertices at render time is overkill. Instead, you can upload the static parts of your geometry to the GPU once, and use transforms to position them relative to each other.

The way to do this in SceneKit is to create separate nodes, each with its own (static) geometry for each piece, then set node transforms (or positions/orientations/scales) to move the nodes relative to one another. To move several nodes at once, use node hierarchy — make several of them children of another node. If some need to move together at one moment, and a different subset need to move together later, you can change the hierarchy.

Here's a concrete example of the Rubik's cube idea. First, creating some cubelets:

```
// convenience for creating solid color materials
func materialWithColor(color: NSColor) -> SCNMaterial {
    let mat = SCNMaterial()
    mat.diffuse.contents = color
    mat.specular.contents = NSColor.whiteColor()
    return mat
}

// create and arrange a 3x3x3 array of cubelets
var cubelets: [SCNNode] = []
for x in -1...1 {
    for y in -1...1 {
        for z in -1...1 {
            let box = SCNBox()
            box.chamferRadius = 0.1
            box.materials = [
                materialWithColor(NSColor.greenColor()),
                materialWithColor(NSColor.redColor()),
                materialWithColor(NSColor.blueColor()),
                materialWithColor(NSColor.orangeColor()),
                materialWithColor(NSColor.whiteColor()),
                materialWithColor(NSColor.yellowColor()),
            ]
            let node = SCNNode(geometry: box)
            node.position = SCNVector3(x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y), z: CGFloat(z))
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
            cubelets += [node]
        }
    }
}
```

Next, the process of doing a rotation. This is one specific rotation, but you could generalize this to a function that does any transform of any subset of the cubelets:

```
// create a temporary node for the rotation
let rotateNode = SCNNode()
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(rotateNode)

// grab the set of cubelets whose position is along the right face of the puzzle,
// and add them to the rotation node
let rightCubelets = cubelets.filter { node in 
    return abs(node.position.x - 1) < 0.001 
}
rightCubelets.map { rotateNode.addChildNode($0) }

// animate a rotation
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(2)
rotateNode.eulerAngles.x += CGFloat(M_PI_2)
SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    // after animating, remove the cubelets from the rotation node,
    // and re-add them to the parent node with their transforms altered
    rotateNode.enumerateChildNodesUsingBlock { cubelet, _ in
        cubelet.transform = cubelet.worldTransform
        cubelet.removeFromParentNode()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cubelet)
    }
    rotateNode.removeFromParentNode()
}
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

The magic part is in the cleanup after the animation. The cubelets start out as children of the scene's root node, and we temporarily re-parent them to another node so we can transform them together. Upon returning them to be the root node's children again, we set each one's local `transform` to its `worldTransform`, so that it keeps the effect of the temporary node's transform changes.

You can then repeat this process to grab whatever set of nodes are in a (new) set of world space positions and use another temporary node to transform those.

I'm not sure quite how Rubik's-cube-like your problem is, but it sounds like you can probably generalize a solution from something like this.

Comment: Your solution 2 is brilliant!

Comment: Thank you SO much. More detail would be EXTREMELY appreciated. In fact the animation of the vertices consists of a multiplication of the position of each 4 vector with a rotation matrix in 2d. All together only manipulation of 4 matrices with simple operations (adding a constant to a certain row) are needed. My problem is that while I did a lot of mathematica programming, in OOP my experience is only the stanford online course and furious learning now... I have quite amazing mathematical shapes, and mathematica is WAY too slow. I was looking at metalkit now.

Comment: If I compute the coords in swift, how do I assemble them into the mesh?           What you suggest is that, say, for a Rubik cube, you can keep the cubelets fixed, but at render time you may do the rotation and the actual coloring? That would be just what I need...

Comment: rickster Sorry, your link to the example is dead. Do you remember anything else about it, so I could find it?